# How to select items in a ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    FileListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "asd1", "asd2" }));

    if (i < 10)
    {
        FileListView.Items[i].Selected = true;
    }
}

FileListView.ItemDrag += new ItemDragEventHandler(FileListView_ItemDrag);
```

but when I Run the application, I can't see the first 10 items selected. For see them, I need to click on one of them, and they will highlights (but of course deselected immediatly, since it is like click on a single row).

How can I preselect 10 items? So a user see them selected and then can click to drag/drop to some destination...

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and it worked just fine. Are you running any other code to focus/select other elements on the form? [example](http://i.imgur.com/OBqSmxb.png)

Comment: I've added the other line I have later, the Drag event linked to the ListView. But I don't think that's matter...

Comment: Where is this code?  I've copied and pasted your code into the constructor, Form_Load(), Form_Shown(), Form_VisibleChanged() and they all work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items are being selected but the control is not activated. Use `FileListView.Select()` to activate the control.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your ListView is not focused so when you select the items they won't highlight.

You can either focus the control before hand like this:

```
FileListView.Focus();
```

Or what's probably better is to disable the [HideSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. This allows the ListView to display selected items when not focused.

```
FileListView.HideSelection = false;
```

**Edit:** With OPs new information that they need to show blue, give keyboard focus to the control once you're done:

```
FileListView.Select();
```

Comment: I've both .Focus (before select them) and Hide selection false. But now I see the selected items gray, not blue! I need blue...

Comment: Sorry, you didn't mention that they had to show blue as if the ListView had keyboard focus. Updated answer, although to be fair I think @Jon just beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the multiselect property with the designer or by code ?

```
 FileListView.MultiSelect=true ;
```

Try also:

```
 FileListView.Invalidate() after the loop.
```

Comment: Other possibility to try : Control.Invalidate()